# Why won't my listbox and scrollbar not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a listbox which has a scrollbar but the following code doesn't seem to show up on the code Please can someone help me fix it?

```
  listbox = Listbox(window2, height = 5)
  listbox.insert(1,"Yr9")
  listbox.insert(1,"Yr10")
  listbox.insert(1,"Yr11")
  listbox.insert(1,"Yr12")
  listbox.insert(1,"Yr13")
  listbox.grid(row=3,column=1)
  sb = Scrollbar(window2,orient=VERTICAL)
  sb.pack()
  listbox = Listbox(window2, yscrollcommand=sb.set)
  sb.config(command=listbox.yview)
  sb.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
  listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: _the following code doesn't seem to show up on the code_. Could you please rephrase this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both the scrollbar and listbox are in `window2`, but you are using `grid` for one and `pack` for the other. Within a given parent window you can only use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use .pack() for both listbox and sb